# Django/Plotly - Click events with JS

Tags: javascript, django, plotly, mouseclick-event

I'm able to simply display my plot (3D scatter) using Plotly. I'm trying to implement a click event feature. Once I click at any of the plot point I'd like to change its color. According to official Plotly documentation it's not that hard: [Plotly - click event](https://plot.ly/javascript/plotlyjs-events/#click-event)

All I can see is that the points I click are being clicked (console logs).
Does anyone got some clue why I'm not able to the change the color in a real time ?

Thanks in advance. Here's my snippets:

**Template:**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block css %}
    <script src="{% static 'js/plotly-latest.min.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div id="single_plot">
        {{ plot_as_div|safe }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block js %}
    <script src="{% static 'js/plot_select_markers.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

**plot_select_markers.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var plot_div_id = $('#single_plot').children().attr('id');

    var plotly_scatter_div = document.getElementById(plot_div_id);

    var color_select = '#7b3294';

    plotly_scatter_div.on('plotly_click', function (data) {
        var pn = '', tn = '', colors = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < data.points.length; i++) {
            pn = data.points[i].pointNumber;
            tn = data.points[i].curveNumber;

            colors = data.points[i].data.marker.color;
        }

        colors[pn] = color_select;

        var update = {
            'marker': {
                color: colors,
                size: 7
            }
        };

        Plotly.restyle(plotly_scatter_div, update, [tn]);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is an issue with `Django` code, but from `plotly js code` I have created a working example for this issue.

Note: There is a problem with `plotly_click` event for `3D-charts`. which makes it go into a `recursive loop`, this issue has been raised in the following [`Github Ticket`](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1025), I have followed their temporary resolution and was able to make the code work.

About the update object.

```
var update = {
    ["marker.color[" + pn + "]"]: color_select,
    ["marker.size[" + pn + "]"]: 7
};
```

You can define the key as `marker.size[0]` to indicate that the first one need to be updated to particular value. Since we are setting the key of the object programatically, I have enclosed the object property in square brackets (`["marker.color[" + pn + "]"]`).

Also please note that you cannot have the properties `size` and `color` as a single property,since you want to update the size/color of a single point. So I have used this simple mockup function `setValue`, which will return an array with the default value as an array of the length of `z properties elements`.

```
function setValue(rows, key, color) {
  return rows.map(function(row) {
    return color;
  });
}
```

Please try out the below code and let me know if your issue is resolved!!

```js
Plotly.d3.csv(
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/3d-scatter.csv",
  function(err, rows) {
    function unpack(rows, key) {
      return rows.map(function(row) {
        return row[key];
      });
    }

    function setValue(rows, key, color) {
      return rows.map(function(row) {
        return color;
      });
    }
    var trace1 = {
      x: unpack(rows, "x1"),
      y: unpack(rows, "y1"),
      z: unpack(rows, "z1"),
      mode: "markers",
      marker: {
        color: setValue(rows, "z1", "rgb(127, 230, 127)"),
        size: setValue(rows, "z1", 20),
        line: {
          color: "rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.14)",
          width: 0.5
        },
        opacity: 0.8
      },
      type: "scatter3d"
    };
    var trace2 = {
      x: unpack(rows, "x2"),
      y: unpack(rows, "y2"),
      z: unpack(rows, "z2"),
      id: unpack(rows, "z2"),
      mode: "markers",
      marker: {
        color: setValue(rows, "z1", "rgb(127, 127, 127)"),
        size: setValue(rows, "z1", 20),
        symbol: "circle",
        line: {
          color: "rgb(204, 204, 204)",
          width: 1
        },
        opacity: 0.9
      },
      type: "scatter3d"
    };
    var data = [trace1, trace2];
    var layout = {
      margin: {
        l: 0,
        r: 0,
        b: 0,
        t: 0
      }
    };
    Plotly.newPlot("myDiv", data, layout);
    var plotly_scatter_div = document.getElementById("myDiv");

    var color_select = "#7b3294";

    plotly_scatter_div.on("plotly_click", function(data) {
      var pn = "",
        tn = "",
        colors = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < data.points.length; i++) {
        pn = data.points[i].pointNumber;
        tn = data.points[i].curveNumber;
        colors = data.points[i].data.marker.color;
      }
      colors[pn] = color_select;

      var update = {
        ["marker.color[" + pn + "]"]: color_select,
        ["marker.size[" + pn + "]"]: 7
      };
      setTimeout(function(x) {
        Plotly.restyle("myDiv", update, tn);
      }, 50);

    });
  }
);
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Plotly.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV -->
  <div id="myDiv" style="width:100%;height:100%"></div>
  <script>
    /* JAVASCRIPT CODE GOES HERE */
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks @NarenMurali for your answer. Unfortunately, it didn't solve my problem. What is more, I also found out there is no need to make it happen in a loop --> https://pastebin.com/CXG1sbpw Once I added your update object I got an exception ---> Uncaught container is not an object

Comment: @tc_qa Please ensure that `size` and `color` property of `marker` is an array of the default value, the array needs to be of length `z`, that is why you are getting this error!!! I have created this array that I am talking about using the function `setValue`

Comment: the difference is in there you're preparing your data inside JS script. My data is taken from numpy arrays. Please assume my script starts by this line --> plotly_scatter_div.on("plotly_click", function(data) {...}

Comment: @tc_qa Ok got it, when you create the plot object in python, just ensure `marker` object properties `color` and `size` are list of length the same as the data present, Thanks for your time!